# Moving SSH keys from Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, debian, migration

I have set up SSH keys on my Ubuntu machine (10.04) and now I am moving to Debian.

On the Debian machine, do I generate new SSH keys corresponding to my username or is it possible to (and is OK) if I copy the `~/.ssh` folder from Ubuntu and place it in the new Debian installation?

Long story short, how do I move around my `SSH` keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy them. There is no need to generate a new pair.